# How can I ignore serializer/deserializer in spring integration?

Tags: spring-integration, tcp

I want to send a file using spring integration tcp module. So I made the server side using tcp-connection-factory.

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="crLfServer" 
        type="server" 
        host="localhost"  
        port="7777"  
        single-use="true"
        so-timeout="10000"
        serializer="serializer"
        deserializer="serializer"
        />

<bean id="serializer" class="com.sds.redca.core.normalizer.CustomSerializerDeserializer" />

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="gatewayCrLf"
    connection-factory="crLfServer"
    request-channel="toSA" 
    error-channel="errorChannel"/>
```

But, I made the client side with pojo class in java like the followings.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SendClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String serverIp = "localhost";
        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            // 서버 연결
            socket = new Socket(serverIp, 7777);
            System.out.println("서버에 연결되었습니다.");

            FileSender fs = new FileSender(socket);
            fs.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class FileSender extends Thread {
    Socket socket;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    FileInputStream fis;
    BufferedInputStream bis;

    public FileSender(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        try {
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String fName = "d:/test2/test.jpg";
            dos.writeUTF(fName);

            File f = new File(fName);
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

            int len;
            int size = 4096;
            byte[] data = new byte[size];
            while ((len = bis.read(data)) != -1) {
                dos.write(data, 0, len);
            }

            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            bis.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I got error like the followings.

```
CRLF not found before max message length: 2048
```

I think I have to ignore serializer/deserializer for communication between two sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't use Spring Integration IP on the client side you should take care about `the end of message` manually.

From other side looks like your `CustomSerializerDeserializer` is an extension of `ByteArrayCrLfSerializer`, because the message `CRLF not found before max message length:` is exactly from there.

So, the first: you should increase the `maxMessageSize` for the `CustomSerializerDeserializer` and second - you have to supply `\r\n` bytes in the end of `write` on the client. Or just use `ByteArrayCrLfSerializer.serialize` there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was great for me.